# Configure Serial port for ethernet

Tags: drivers, ethernet, ubuntu-18.04, rs232

I have an unmarked cable that adapts an rs232 serial port to an Ethernet jack. How do I configure my ubuntu 18.04 machine to work with it?

Comment: Have you looked at this for transmitting serial signals over Ethernet cable.  https://www.perle.com/products/serial-to-ethernet.shtml?gclid=Cj0KCQjw09HzBRDrARIsAG60GP8u3YjHbar2DCQCeO5m_XrLfJQRWnq0vHqJMW-9W_F-ijBQbIS4XzkaAqTvEALw_wcB

Comment: But I'm not trying to use a serial port over ethernet, Im trying to use it as ethernet

Comment: Ethernet does not work over serial cable. The other way can work, but not Ethernet over serial

Comment: *"unmarked cable that adapts an rs232 serial port to an Ethernet jack"* -- Please post a photo of this cable.  You seem to be conflating connectors with signals/interfaces.  Older connectors (such as DB-9, DB-25, and RJ-45) are generic, and can be (and have been) used with any signal/interface that doesn't exceed the electrical capabilities of the hardware.  In contrast, most modern connections (e.g. SATA, USB, HDMI) have been designed by and owned by organizations for an interface.  IOW that cable probably does not convert a serial port to Ethernet (although such devices do exist!).

Answer (score 0):

> I have an unmarked cable that adapts an rs232 serial port to an
>   Ethernet jack.

Just use a proper Ethernet Cable to connect the Ethernet Jack to your Ubuntu Machine.

Ethernet is multiple twisted pairs and the capacitance between pairs matters. So Ethernet does not work over a Serial Cable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the description correctly, but what I guess is following.

The small cable is intended to be plugged into a serial port interface.

Its purpose is probably to allow using standard ethernet cables as a serial interface cable.

This allows you for example in an office where network cables are already placed in the floor to go have a serial cable go across a huge office without having to add new specific serial cables.

**You cannot use a serial cable reliably for an ethernet connection.**